# tinkerpop/gremlin-python: next() vs iterate()

Tags: gremlin, gremlinpython

What is the difference between next() and iterate() when working with gremlin? Why does next() return the added vertex when calling `g.addV()`, but iterate() does not? When should I use next() and when should I use iterate()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is already in your question. You'll use `.next()`, when you need the result (and you are expecting exactly one result), and you'll use `.iterate()`, when you don't need the result (typically mutation queries, that add/change properties, edges and/or vertices).

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you expect more than one result, `.toList()` will return a list of all the results.