# Convert GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, List>> into Java8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I have a result of a query to `graphDB` which returns `GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, List>> values`. By using the default methods `values.iterate().toStream()` it should return a Stream of `Stream<Map<Object, List>>` which I can handle as a Java8 stream, but for some reason, it does not work, repeat, by using the default methods from gemlin API to get the stream.

Note: By using a `while` I can iterate over it, that's fine, but I need to do some more complex operations that will be simplified by using `Java8 Streams`, but, as I said, is not working, even using `tinkerpop` default methods. Any idea?

There are no errors, but the stream is empty for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried using `toList()` rather than `iterate()` ? The `iterate` terminal step includes an implicit `none` step and therefore does not return any result to the caller. Here is a related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024185/tinkerpop-gremlin-python-next-vs-iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `iterate()` it returns a `GraphTraversal` and you can then call `toStream()` on that, but it will always be empty. You should omit the `iterate()` if you intend to return values to your `Stream`. In short, simply  do `values().toStream()`.